# Error. Acceso denegado al usuario 'root' después de poner contraseña en phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp, localhost

he estado trabajando con el servidor local XAMMP, todo iba bien hasta que decidí cambiar la contraseña de acceso al panel phpMyAdmin (por motivos seguridad).
**¿Cómo lo resuelvo sin perder mi base de datos?** Ya probé re-configurar desde el archivo *`config.inc.php`* poniendo la contraseña que puse en phpmyadmin, pero no se resolvió, ni al poner los valores por defecto!
[image: Ahora no puedo acceder]

Comment: Si estás usando la autenticación mediante cookies (`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';`) entonces basta con que teclees la nueva contraseña en el formulario de entrada. No se recomienda usar la autenticación `config` e introducir el usuario y contraseña del usuario `root` en el archivo de configuración ya que cualquiera con acceso a tu phpMyAdmin podría entrar con máximos privilegios. [Ver documentación](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/es/latest/config.html#cfg_Servers_auth_type).

Comment: No me aparece el formulario de entrada. No más ingresar en el navegar: **localhost** me abre el panel principal, pero al dirigirme a **phpMyAdmin** me sale el error sin opción a nada

Comment: Bueno, voy a desglosar mi comentario por partes. **1.-** Abre el archivo de configuración `config.inc.php`. **2.-** Busca allá donde tienes configurado `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';` y cambia el valor de `'config'` a `'cookie'`. **3.-** Ahora te aparecerá un formulario preguntándote usuario y contraseña al acceder a la página del phpmyadmin. Por último: ¿cómo cambiaste la contraseña del usuario `root`?

Comment: Si has cambiado la clave del usuario `root` modificando manualmente el registro de la tabla `user` de base de datos `mysql` o simplemente la has olvidado, entonces es probable que tengas que iniciar el [procedimiento de restablecimiento de contraseña](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html#resetting-permissions-generic) indicado en la documentación y volver a introducir una contraseña para el usuario `root` de manera correcta. Si sólo cambiaste la contraseña del usuario `root` en el archivo de configuración, entonces deberás cambiarla dentro de MySQL.

Comment: Hasta ahí todo bien. Ya me apareció el formulario de entrada. pero no acepta el usuario** root** y la **contraseña que le asigné** en **usuarios/editar privilegios/contraseña sí** (puse y confirmé una contraseña) y luego **continuar.** después de eso intenté abrir una tabla. Así comenzó todo. Gracias

Comment: Es probable que pusieras mal la contraseña o que la teclearas incorrectamente. Lo mejor es usar siempre la consulta SQL, en la que estás viendo la contraseña en texto plano mientras la tecleas y no hay error posible: `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'nueva_clave';`. Si no consigues entrar entonces deberás iniciar el proceso de restablecimiento de contraseña que te enlacé anteriormente.

Comment: EFECTIVAMENTE... Puse mal la contraseña. Quería ponerla en **minúsculas,**  y no me di cuenta de que tenía activada **MAYUS**. Estoy de nuevo a mi DataBase. **GRACIAS!** jjJJjjJJ

Comment: ¡De nada! ¡Un placer! :D

Comment: Sudaste frio, bro?

Answer (score 0):

En **config.inc.php**

Cambia:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
```

Por:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
```

Comment: no olvides $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'tupassword'